# Get Specific data from access database

Tags: asp.net, database

I have a login form which require two fields. One is for email and other is password. I want to get email and password from database and then match it with user entered email and password.
So far I have done this.

```
public int checkLogin(String email,String pass)
{
    try
    {
        conn = new OleDbConnection();
        cmd = new OleDbCommand();
        da = new OleDbDataAdapter();
        ds = new DataSet();

        conn.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=E:\\Users\\He Man\\Documents\\Project.accdb";
        conn.Open();
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT Email, [Password] FROM UserProfile"
                +" where Email='"+email+"' and Password='"+pass+"';";
        int checkPoint=0;
        da.SelectCommand = cmd;
        da.Fill(ds);

        for (int i = 0; i < ds.Tables["UserProfile"].Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            if (ds.Tables["UserProfile"].Rows[i]["Email"].ToString() == email && ds.Tables["UserProfile"].Rows[i]["[Password]"].ToString() == pass)
            {
               checkPoint = 1;
            }
            else
            {
               checkPoint =0;
            }
        }
        conn.Close();
        return checkPoint;
   }
   catch(Exception)
   {
      return 0;
   }

}
```

It returns 1 if data match and 0 if didn't match kindly help. I just wanted to match my data to each data value in the dataset.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are doing too many things wrong.

1. you absolutely don't need to do this

   ```
   if (ds.Tables["UserProfile"].Rows[i]["Email"].ToString() == email ...
   ```

   because, your query has a `where` condition, i.e. if the Username and password won't match, your DataSet is going to be empty, so you should better check, whether your ds is empty or not.
2. You are prone to `SQL Injection`. A 7th Grade kid can drop your entire database. Do NOT USE Concatenated string as your command query, use parameterized one, i.e.

   ```
   query = "Select Count(*) From UserProfile Where Username= @username and 
           Password=@password";

   OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(query, conn);
   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", txtUsername.Text);
   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", txtPassword.Text);
   int result = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
   if(result.Equals(1))
   {
       //successful login
   }
   else
   {
      //login failed
   }
   ```
3. you should'nt be creating `Connection` and `Command` object everywhere, you can create class wrapping all these db-details and exposing functions accepting only querystring and parameters as arguments and returning dataset or scalar result, something like:

   ```
   public DataTable GetSelectQueryResult(string query, OleDbParameter[] parameters)
   {
       var con = GetConnection();
       //rest of the logic
   }
   ```

Comment: Thank you sir for helping.. I have noticed my mistakes next time I wont repeat it.

Comment: Sir do you know any good tutorial for CRUD operations of access database.Kindly share.

Comment: visit www.asp.net site, they have lots of tutorial for both beginners and advance users, Note that OleDb and Sql data objects are exactly same, tutorials for any will server for both (in almost all cases)

Answer (score 1):

replace this:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < ds.Tables["UserProfile"].Rows.Count; i++)
 {
    if (ds.Tables["UserProfile"].Rows[i]["Email"].ToString() == email && ds.Tables["UserProfile"].Rows[i]["[Password]"].ToString() == pass)
    {
      checkPoint = 1;
    }
    else
    {
      checkPoint = 0;
    }
 }
```

with:

```
checkPoint = ds.Tables["UserProfile"].Rows.Count>0 ? 1 : 0;
```